# Unboxing nullable types - workaround?

Tags: c#

I'm storing an update operation as thus:

```
class Update
{
    public Expression MemberExpression { get; set; }
    public Type FieldType { get; set; }
    public object NewValue { get; set; }
}
```

For example:

```
var myUpdate = new Update
{
    MemberExpression = (MyType o) => o.LastModified,
    FieldType = typeof(DateTime?),
    NewValue = (DateTime?)DateTime.Now
}
```

Then I'm trying to apply this update later (simplified):

```
var lambda = myUpdate.MemberExpression as LambdaExpression;
var memberExpr = lambda.Body as MemberExpression;
var prop = memberExpr.Member as PropertyInfo;
prop.SetValue(item, myUpdate.Value);
```

However, `myUpdate.Value` is a `DateTime`, not a `DateTime?`.  This is because when you cast a nullable to an `object`, it either becomes `null` or boxes the value type.

Since `(DateTime?)myUpdate.Value` would work to get it back to the correct type, I tried to simulate this compile-time construct using `Convert.ChangeType`.  However, it says that casting from `DateTime` to `DateTime?` is not possible.

What approach can I use here to get the object back into its original type?

Is there any way to store a nullable types, regular structs and regular objects in a single field, and get the exact thing stored into it back again?

Comment: What is your problem? Does `prop.SetValue(item, myUpdate.Value);` throw any exception for you?

Comment: How could you hope the `Convert.ChangeType` method could be useful? It is a non-generic method whose declared return type is `object`. So because of the boxing conventions for `Nullable<>` you mention yourself, the returned box from that method cannot be of type `Nullable<>`.

Comment: PetSerAl - yes, since the types don't match.  Sorry, perhaps not as obvious as I thought!

Comment: @DavidL - thanks, this was in fact the code I was using.  My exception was regarding the other parameter and I didn't realise :)

Comment: To be specific: the member access expression was on a sub-property.  E.g. o => o.SomeProperty.SubProperty.  So the member access expression was for the SomeProperty.SubProperty, but I was passing the 'o' to SetValue.  So my answer below handles this case, too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the type of your Expression when you create myUpdate, `SetInfo()` will properly set your data, even if boxing/unboxing.

```
public class Update
{
    public Expression MemberExpression { get; set; }
    public Type ClassType { get; set; }
    public object NewValue { get; set; }
}

public class MyType
{
    public DateTime? LastModified { get; set; }
}

void Main()
{
    var myUpdate = new Update
    {
        MemberExpression = 
            (Expression<Func<MyType, DateTime?>>)((MyType o) => o.LastModified),
        ClassType = typeof(MyType),
        NewValue = DateTime.Now
    };

    // At a later point where we do not want to instantiate via strong typing
    var item = Activator.CreateInstance(myUpdate.ClassType);

    var lambda = myUpdate.MemberExpression as LambdaExpression;
    var memberExpr = lambda.Body as MemberExpression;
    var prop = memberExpr.Member as PropertyInfo;

    prop.SetValue(item, myUpdate.NewValue);

    item.Dump();
}
```

This properly outputs a DateTime value corresponding to when it was created without an exception.

Comment: Indeed you are correct, and my original code was correct too.  SetValue was throwing 'System.Reflection.TargetException: Object does not match target type.'.  I was that NewValue was DateTime and the property was DateTime? and guessed it was that.  .....in fact, my 'item' was not the correct type: simply the wrong object being passed in, my bug/error from elsewhere.

Comment: @KierenJohnstone Makes perfect sense. I've done that many times.  Glad it helped!

Comment: I also found that I can build a new expression: Expression.Assign(memberExpression, Expression.Constant(newValue)) and put that into a lambda, compile and run it.. no reflection then!  I'll post as a separate answer but keep this as the correct one

Comment: In fact, this code doesn't work where a sub-property is required.  Would you be offended if I marked my answer instead? :|

Comment: @KierenJohnstone I wouldn't be offended no, but that also was not specified in the original question so technically your answer meets more than the original question, whereas my answer met exactly what the question asked for :)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use a generic class?

```
class Update<TField>
{
  public Expression<Func<MyType, TField>> MemberExpression { get; set; }
  public TField NewValue { get; set; }
}
```

Not sure if you can just use a plain `Func<MyType, TField>` delegate instead of the expression tree, for your use.

Comment: In fact I tried this, but what I have is an array of these, with the TField not known in advance.  This would need to derive a base class - and MemberExpression would become an Expression again, unless Im missing a trick?

Comment: @KierenJohnstone Yes, I can see no solution for that.

Comment: If you do not want the special boxing conversion for `Nullable<T>` (where `T` could be `DateTime`), you could use e.g. a `Tuple<DateTime>` reference (this is a reference type), or write your own `struct Maybe<T>` which does just like `Nullable<T>` but has ordinary boxing convention.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve using expressions and no reflection too:

```
        var lambda = update.MemberExpression as LambdaExpression;
        var memberExpr = lambda.Body as MemberExpression;
        if (memberExpr == null)
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException("Field expression must be a member expression");
        }

        // do a cast - this ensures nullable types work, for instance
        var cast = Expression.Convert(Expression.Constant(update.Value), update.FieldType);

        // assign the target member with the cast value
        var assignment = Expression.Assign(memberExpr, cast);

        // build a new lambda, no return type, which does the assignment
        var newLambda = Expression.Lambda(typeof(Action<T>), assignment, lambda.Parameters[0]);

        // compile to something we can invoke, and invoke
        var compiled = (Action<T>)newLambda.Compile();

        compiled(item);
```

And voila, the item is modified :)